# while loop and counting down from 20

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and I wanted to know, how do you write a program to count down from 20?  Also, how do you incorporate the said program with the "while" and "if" loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it

```
x = 20

while x > 0:
    print(x)
    x -= 1
```

If you need to include an if statement in the loop, you could do this instead.

```
x = 20

while True:
    print(x)
    x -= 1
    if x == 0:
      break
```

If you wanted to do this with a for loop, it would look like this:

```
for x in range(1, 20):
    print(x)
```

If you wanted to do it all in one line, you could do this. Just note that it doesn't use a while loop or an if statement.

```
print("\n".join([str(x) for x in range(20, 0, -1)]))
```

Comment: Thanks you.  Just 2 other quick questions,  would I need the range? how would I see the numbers counting down from 10,9,8.......,1?

Comment: You only need the range if you're doing the one line solution. If you want to go from 10 to 1, change 20 to 10.

Comment: I need the "while loop" and the "for loop"

Comment: I just added a for loop example to my answer.

Comment: Thank Jake.  I'll try it now.  been stuck for Hours so hopefully this helps.  really appreciate your prompt response

Comment: @S.James Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Click the checkmark below an answer. See [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for details.